# Separate specific characters in a list with strings

Tags: python, string, list, indexing

I have this list:

```
List:
00001:GR00034.asd
00001:GR00020.asd
00001:GR00002.asd
...
```

I want to convert these lines in something like this:

```
List:
GR34
GR20
GR2
...
```

I've tried using loops but I can't make it  work:

(indexes is  the first list presented before)

```
for idx in indexes: #to limit between  the ":" and the "."

    i = ((idx).index(":"))
    f = ((idx.index(".")))
    idx = idx[i+1:f]
    list1 = []

    for pos in idx: #Iterate trough each character in idx
        if pos.isalpha():
            list1.append(pos)
        else:
            if pos != "0":
                list1.append(pos)
                if idx[-1] == 0: #to add a 0 at the end if necessary 
                   list1+=0
```

My output is this:

```
Index List:
1      G
2      R
3      2
4      1
```

(Just appears the **last** iteration and separated)

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't make it work". What happens when you run your code? Please give example output. Also be sure that we can copy/paste your code and run it ourselves. See [mcve] for tips on creating a good code example. Your current code has a variable `indexes` that is never declared and a `return` in the global scope.

Comment: It creates a list that looks like: [(GR), (2),(0)],and just appears the info from the  first iteration

Comment: Two tips: `if pos.isalpha() == True` can be reduced to `if pos.isalpha()`. And `list1 += [pos]` can be changed to `list1.append(pos)`.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Please [edit] your question to include the example output and fix the errors in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is stems from the fact your "list1" variable is nested inside the for loop. This means that everytime your loop is iterated, list1 gets reset. To avoid that, you have to define list1 outside of the loop and append to it at the end of each loop. For example:

```
list1 = []
for idx in indexes: #to limit between  the ":" and the "."

    i = ((idx).index(":"))
    f = ((idx.index(".")))
    idx = idx[i+1:f]
    entry = ""
    for pos in idx: #Iterate trough each character in idx

        if pos.isalpha():
            entry = entry + pos
        else:
            if pos != "0":
                entry = entry + pos
                if idx[-1] == '0': #to add a 0 at the end if necessary 
                    entry = entry + '0'
        
    list1.append(entry)
```

Here I defined a new variable "entry" that will add all the desired character through the loop, and before the loop resets, I append entry to list1 giving us the characters "G" "R" and non-zeros.

This gives the output:
['GR34', 'GR20', 'GR2']

Comment: I'm not sure. If all items in your list of index follows the same pattern as the ones you posted, then this code should work in general. I would need to see your list of index to see what is up. Otherwise, if you just need a small fix, perhaps you can just start your list at the 5th element. List = List[4:]

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so to add to patrick7's post,the final two lines should have 0 as a string, not as an integer

```
 if idx[-1] == "0": #to add a 0 at the end if necessary 
      list1+="0"
```